# Using thematic layer for segmentation in eCognition?

Tags: ecognition, image-segmentation, image-classification

I have a thematic layer, i want to perform segmentation and classification only within the thematic layer,not in a whole image. how can i do it? I tried to segment the image after viewing the thematic layer in view setting and the thematic layer usage was enabled, but it was segmenting the whole image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach to this would be to do it in multiple steps:

1. Chessboard segmentation with a very large object size, using thematic layers
2. Assign class, using 'Number of overlaps', into two classes, "Outside AOI" and "Inside AOI"
3. Do additional segmentation on object level, rather than pixel level, using the "Inside AOI" class only.